# Bump functions and compact sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Recently I came across a remark in my lecture note:

> For any compact sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ with $K_1\subset U \subset K_2\subset \Bbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is open, there exists a function $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi\equiv 1$ in $K_1$ and $\varphi\equiv 0$ outside $K_2$.

I want to prove this claim, so I assume that we need to use the characteristic function $\chi$.
However, this function not smooth. Therefore, I think that taking the convolution of the characteristic functions with a mollifier can solve this problem, however I don't know how to do this. Is this a well known result? How can I prove this.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sketch of a possible way of proving this result:

Take a compact set $K_3\neq K_2$ such that $K_2\subset K_3$ and define $F=K_3\setminus\text{int}(K_2)$.

Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}d(K_1,F)$ and define
$$K_0=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid d(x,K_1)\leq \varepsilon\},\qquad F_0=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid d(x,K_1)\geq 2\varepsilon\}.$$

Now, define
$$v(x)=\frac{d(x,F_0)}{d(x,F_0)+d(x,K_0)},\quad x\in\mathbb R^n$$
and take a function $\theta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $$\theta\geq 0, \quad \text{supp}(\theta)=\overline{B_\varepsilon(0)},\quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\theta(x)\;dx=1.$$

The function $\varphi=\theta*v$ has the desired properties (and also $0\leq \varphi\leq 1$).

**Remark.** This argument proves the following more general result:

> Let $K_1\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a comapct set and $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a closed set such that $K_1\cap F=\varnothing$. Then there exists $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi=1$ in $K_1$, $\varphi=0$ in $F$ and $0\leq\varphi\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where do we need to use the compactness of $K_1,K_2,K_3$ and that $U$ is open?

Comment: @DispN We want a smooth function that equals $1$ in some region $K_1$ and equals $0$ in some region $F$, which is disjoint of $K_1$. If there is no open set $U$ disjoint of $F$ such that $K_1\subset U$, then the continuity of such a function can be impossible (we need a region between $K_1$ and $F$ to join the graph continuously). In the proof, we need $K_1$ compact and $F$ closed in order to get $\varepsilon>0$. Thus, in your problem, $K_3$ is taken compact to make $F:=K_3\setminus\text{int}(K_2)$ closed.

Comment: @DispN Note that the proof is essentially a mollification of the Urysohn's function (Proposition 4.13 [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=i3FYIWIYu5QC&pg=PA119&dq=%22urysohn+function%22+%22metric+space%22&hl=en&ei=n1IETseaJors-gbI0b21DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22urysohn%20function%22%20%22metric%20space%22&f=false)).