# Is the laplacian of this test functions bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

An open ball $B$  in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is given. We are looking for a sequence $(\phi_{j})_{j}$ of $C_{c}^{\infty}(B)$ and a  sequence $(K_{j})_{j}$  of compact sets such that:

1) the compact sets $(K_{j})_{j}$ are increasing and their union  equals $B$,

2) for each natural number $j$, the laplacian $\Delta \phi_{j}=1$ on $K_{j}$ and its support is in $K_{j+1}$,

3) the sequence $(\phi_{j})_{j}$ satisfies
$$\sup_{(x,j)\in B\times\mathbb{N}}|\Delta\phi_{j}(x)|<\infty.$$

My question is: does this problem have a solution?

Comment: Define $K_j=\{x\in B\mid d(x,\partial B)\geq \frac{r}{j}\}$ where $r$ is the radius of the given ball. As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2057878/70305), there exists $\varphi_j\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\varphi_j=1$ in $K_j$, $\varphi_j=0$ in $\mathbb R^n\setminus (K_{j+1})^\circ$ and $0\leq\varphi_j\leq 1$. From the [existence theorem for Poisson's equation](https://goo.gl/sxbvrK), there exists $\phi_j\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $\Delta\phi_j=\varphi_j$.

Comment: This gives you a sequence $(\phi_{j})_{j}$ in $C^{\infty}(B)$ and a  sequence $(K_{j})_{j}$ of compact sets satysfying (1), (2) and (3). So the question is if you can ensure that the said solution for the Poisson's equation and its derivatives have support in $B$. Maybe the [representation formula](http://math.mit.edu/~jspeck/18.152_Fall2011/Lecture%20notes/18152%20lecture%20notes%20-%209.pdf) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by an almost identical argument to my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471633/is-the-laplacian-of-these-test-functions-bounded). By the divergence theorem,

$$0=\int \Delta\phi_j=\int_{K_j} \Delta\phi_j+\int_{K_{j+1}\setminus K_j} \Delta\phi_j=\operatorname{vol}(K_j)+\int_{K_{j+1}\setminus K_j}\Delta\phi_j,$$
so
$$\sup(-\Delta\phi_j)\geq \frac{1}{\operatorname{vol}(K_{j+1}\setminus K_j)}\int_{K_{j+1}\setminus K_j}-\Delta\phi_j = \frac{\operatorname{vol}(K_j)}{\operatorname{vol}(K_{j+1}\setminus K_j)}\to\infty.$$